# Using an AsyncImageView in android has a strange padding I can't remove

Tags: android, layout, android-xml

I'm using the AsyncImageView from GreenDroid( https://github.com/kennydude/GreenDroid ) and it has made my view go all strange. It's in a TwoLineLayout (or whatever it's called), and it's showing me some unexpected padding which using the ddms it's from the actual AsyncImageView itself and I can't figure out why it's there, because the image is correctly sized as the corners go on fine.

I've tried using all the ScaleTypes and don't like how Matrix zooms everything in. Here's the XML currently: http://pastebin.com/H1kFpiTM

Also bellow is a screenshot of what I get, which you can see the strange gap.

[image]

Thanks in Advance,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it! It's due to some new code which was "automatically" selecting the correct image size to download. It was incorrect and so the imageview was scalling the image to fit.

Comment: Please post a solution, I have the same problem with that strange top and bottom padding after image is loaded.

Comment: Aha! You pinged me on Twitter, I don't really understand much on how the ImageView works, but thanks for posting your solution for anyone who comes across this problem themselves! Tops to you!

Answer (score 2):

For me, solution was :

```
image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
image.invalidate();
```